# How do I add a prefix to log4j messages (at the object level)

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I use log4j2 and I would like to add a prefix to all my messages. This prefix is passed to the constructor parameter and it depends on the instance of the class. So we're at the object level (not class or thread).

For example, I have an `A` class instantiated like `new A(152)`, so when I use `log.error("message")` on this class, `152:` is written just before the message. For `new A(155)`, `155:` will be displayed instead.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If log4j2 supports the MDC you Can put it in there.

Comment: Good suggestion. It does support MDC

Comment: Thanks it's works with ThreadContext in log4j2

Comment: Is it possible to put multiple values for one key ?

Comment: Different threads can put different values for the same key. The map is threadlocal so every thread has a separate copy.

Comment: Finally I created a class LogMessage which implement MessageFactory ans I concatenate message with prefix. After I create logger like this `private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyClass", new LogMessage(prefix));` and it's work

Answer (score 7):

Use MDC to achive this

In your constructor put

```
 MDC.put("prefix", yourvalue);
```

and in your XML use it like this in pattern

```
      %X{prefix}
```

Comment: Different threads can put different values for the same key. The map is threadlocal so every thread has a separate copy.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Bill Clars answer:

```
public class LogWrapper
{
    private Logger log;
    private String prefix;

    public LogWrapper(Logger log, String prefix) {
        this.log = log;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public void error(String msg)
    {
        log.error(prefix + ": " + msg);
    }
}
```

Then you set as instance variable in your class

```
public class MyClass {
    private LogWrapper log;

    public MyClass(int prefix) {
        log = new LogWrapper(Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()), String.valueOf(prefix));

        // then log away
        log.error("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could extend `Logger` and override the logging methods

Comment: I tried this before... It will always print the exact same `file:line` as the log message origin. It will always be `LogWrapper:26` because you log4j logger call is at line (e.g.) 26 in your `LogWrapper` class. You'd need to extend the log4j logger, but that's still not trivial (at least, it wasn't on log4j 1.2).

Comment: As I understood it the question asked to simply prefix a number before all messages...

Comment: I'm just pointing out that, although answering the question, it's not very practical since you are losing valuable information. Unless you don't care where your logs come from, in which case I'd wonder why you're logging using a logging framework and not simply printing the desired information to a file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one simple workaround solution: you can **wrap the string with a method** that adds the prefix to it and returns concatenated string to the `error` method.

```
public class A {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

    final int index;

    public A(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static void f(String message) {
        return String.valueOf(index) + ": ";
    }

    public void method() {

        // ...

        LOG.error(f("message"));

    }

}
```

Advantages:

- Simple
- You can log messages with and also without the prefix in one class/method
- You don't have to permanently add something like `%X{prefix}` to the log4j2 configuration

Disadvantages:

- You always have to use the wrapper method if you want to add the prefix

Comment: And if you want to use this wrapper method in each class you create, you can use static import instead of declaring the method in each class

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a wrapper class.

```
public class YourLogger
{
    private Logger log;

    public void error(int value, String msg)
    {
        log.error(String.valueOf(value) + ": " + msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this but the calling class and the line number are lost.

Comment: @Boubee i thing your variable contain effected code line number.is it ?

Comment: No, my variable is a serial number

Comment: See comment I wrote on DiaryLea's answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void writeError(String msg,int intValue) {
logger.error(intValue+" "+msg);
}
```

Comment: With this, wouldn't you have to create a method for each logging level, in each class you create?

Comment: yes i know no need to create seprate methods.for OP 'S  understanding i wrote this.