# How to add prefix to all logs written by Spring Boot?

Tags: logging, spring-boot, logback

We are developing a Multi Tenant Application. I want to add the tenant name before each log message

....  [liquiforce] New User John Kid created

..... [moreiq]     Fetched 4 Samples for Project 12

In the above example the

1. "..." denotes the usual time stamp, process id, log level, class names e.g 2016-03-28 21:15:35.219  WARN 8 --- [           main] d.s.r.o.OperationImplicitParameterReader :
2. [liquiforce] is my tenant name. The first log is from an action from liquiforce tenant and second from moreiq tenant
3. I will be referring to the tenant information from the SecurityContext of Spring

This is all part of spring boot which uses default logback logging.

Cheers,
Rohit

Comment: Did you thought about using MDC?

Comment: Using logback, you can configure the pattern of your logs in the logback.xml file. Some variables already contain level, date, method, etc. In your code, you can define your own variable if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to configure in `logback-spring.xml`, take a look at the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322709/unable-to-use-spring-property-placeholders-in-logback-xml).
If you prefer to configure in Java code, take a look at the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723016/how-do-i-add-a-prefix-to-log4j-messages-at-the-object-level).

Anyway, using `logback-spring.xml` is better, here is an example.

```
<springProperty name="prefix" source="spring.prefix"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${prefix} - %msg</file>
</appender>
```